# How to send email while also sending details to PayPal at the same time with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am new to PHP and have created a shopping small shopping cart that is sending the details to paypal which is working but I also want the customer to fill out their shipping address and have that emailed to a email address when the click on the check out button.

I am not sure the best way to go about this, the reason I need this form is because if they select VIC for the state then shipping is free, the $_SESSION['shipping_cost'] holds the cost.

Can I have to actions somehow so I could just combine the shipping address form and the paypal?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
            </textarea><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@email.com">
            <?php $this->pay_pal(); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
            <input type="image" onclick="return checkConditions();" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but03.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.somewhere.com">
        </form>
```

Comment: usual process is to wait until pypal conforms payment before sending the email

Comment: yea i know and that would be fine but I send the shipping price to paypal and wanted to change that to $0 if they are located in VIC so needed them to fill in those details first...

Comment: most carts have a confirm page before going to the payment gateway- this makes things easy. address form> process postage\show confirm page>payment gateway

Comment: yea but this cart just hold the $id of the item and loops the detail out on the same page as the items (there is not many) and then when you click the paypal button it sends the details to paypal. Next time I will design it differently but was hoping just for this one I could figure something out.

Comment: A form can only have/do 1 action. If you want to do 2 different actions you will need to use javascript (w/ Ajax) to send your shipping form at the same time as your paypal form.

Answer (score 4):

just like almoullim said

you can download phpmailer from here

> http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

and here is the tutorial for it

> http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/sending-email-with-phpmailer-and-smtp

Answer (score 0):

in the page that will take the visitor to PayPal put another code for sending a mail
you can use PHPMailer

in my case i made a CMS
and when anyone install the CMS script on his website
its send me an email 
that some one has installed my CMS script and with the URL for the site
so ican know that if my script usefull or not and if there is any errors

i used PHPmailer and with SMTP

using this code

```
  if (isset($_POST['send']) and $_POST['send'] == 'sendmail') {

$sendmail = require_once('../lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    include("../lib/phpmailer/class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within          class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

  $mail             = new PHPMailer();

 $body = "
 <br>
 Website Name : $qr->sname
 <br>
 Website url : $qr->surl
<br>
$qmsg";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "mail@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "pass";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('$qemail', 'Almoullim CMS');

$mail->Subject    = "Almoullim CMS Report - $qsubject";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "mail@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Almoullim CMS");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
}

if (isset($sendmail)) {
die ("
        <center>
        <div class='head'>تــــــــم</div>
        <div class='bodypanel'>
        <br>
        ارســـــال التــــقرير بنــــجاح
        <br>
        <br>
        </div>
        </center>
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='4; url=?cpages=report' />
");


}
}
?>
```